# Rendering object in OpenGL causes the object to be compressed on X axis

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I'm creating a simple rendering engine. But when rendering a cube it is compressed on the X axis 3 times:

```
void Transformation::defaultPosition()
{
    positionMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
}

void Transformation::defaultScale()
{
    scaleMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
}

void Transformation::defaultRotation()
{
    rotationQuat = glm::quat(1.0, 0, 0, 0);
}
Transformation::Transformation()
{
    defaultPosition();
    defaultScale();
   defaultRotation();
}

glm::mat4x4 Transformation::M()
{
    return positionMatrix * glm::toMat4(rotationQuat) * scaleMatrix;
}


GameObject::GameObject(Texture* texture, ShaderProgram* program, Mesh* mesh)
{
    this->texture = texture;
    dir = glm::vec3(1, 0, 0);
    meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, program);
    transform.setRotation(1.57, 1, 0, 0);
    transform.translate(glm::vec3(0, -2, 0));
    transform.setScale(glm::vec3(1, 1, 1));
    transform.setPosition(glm::vec3(0, 0, 5));
}

void GameObject::draw(glm::mat4x4 projectionMatrix, glm::mat4x4 viewMatrix, glm::mat4x4 parentTransform)
{
    glm::mat4x4 worldTransform = transform.M() * parentTransform;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->getGLindx());
    meshRenderer->bind();

    glUniformMatrix4fv(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("modelMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(worldTransform));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("viewMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(viewMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("projectionMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("normalMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(glm::transpose(glm::inverse(worldTransform))));
    glUniform3f(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("lightPos"), 3, 3, -300);
    glUniform3f(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("u_lightDirection"), -3, -3, -5);
    glUniform3f(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("u_ambientLight"), 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    meshRenderer->render();
    meshRenderer->unbind();
}
```

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 140

in vec3 VertexPosition;
in vec3 VertexNormal;
in vec2 VertexUV;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;

out vec3 norm;
out vec3 fragPos;
out vec2 UV;

void main() {
    UV = VertexUV;
    norm = mat3(normalMatrix) * VertexNormal;
    fragPos = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1));
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1 );
}
```

Comment: What resolution are you rendering? If your view & projection matrices don't take this into account, your images are going to be as if the pixels are squared, which they are not.

Comment: rendering in thart sense is fine. i can move aroudn the cube. but its not a cube. its compressed on global x axis. not just visual thing

Comment: Hmm that quaternion (1.57, 1, 0, 0) looks like it's not a unit-quaternion. Try normalizing that.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as a base.

Comment: @StarShine I changed that and few more things and its fixed... All i did was to swap my manual code for the glm inbuilt stuff... maybe i made some mistake then...